# Replace values/keys in array function

Tags: php

I am looking for function which will replace array keys, for example: 
change this array:

```
array(0 => a, 1 => b, 2 => c)
```

to:

```
array(0 => a, 1 => c, 2 => b)
```

so i have array keys 0,1,2 and their values, and i want to change value of key 1and replace it with value from key 2, i hope i was cleare,
thanks

Comment: But 0th key and the corresponding value stays the same, what's the logic here?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul don't see proble, 0th key is in both cases same, just replace first and second

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php ?, other than that, your question is super unclear

Comment: @Neat don't want random choice

Comment: Your question is more like interchanging the values. Use this function, `function interchange(&$a){ $t = $a[1]; $a[1] = $a[2]; $a[2] = $t; }` and call this function with your array.

Comment: `array_combine(array_with_new_keys, old_array);`